# Display Aerials as greyscale?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know about google styled maps, which allow me to control the look of the google basemap.
I want to be able to pull in the aerial imagery from Google into my application, but have it displayed as greyscale as opposed to colour?

Is it possible to retrieve the aerials in greyscale from google via the default v3 API?

Comment: This is as close as I can find so far - http://snipplr.com/view/63328

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this example by Odoe which uses css filters on the maps? Might be limited outside of chrome

http://www.odoe.net/apps/mapstyler/

https://github.com/odoe/MapStyler